# Problem formulation classification task

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model, supervised-learning, function

I would like to know if it is correct for a classification task in a supervised learning to say the model we are looking for is a function from RxR to a discrete space
$$
f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \rightharpoonup\left\{ Label1,Label2\right\}
$$

Comment: How many predictor variables do you have?

Comment: I have 15 inputs and 2 ouputs. My inputs are mixed with float and integer.

Comment: Then I am curious how you wound up with $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

No, I say that both sides are incorrect in general.

If you have two predictor variables, both of which can take any real value, then the left is fine. If you have three such variables, you need another $\times\mathbb R$. If your predictor variables are categorical, then I would not call them variables on all of $\mathbb R$.

For the right side, your function likely outputs probability values. Consequently, I would consider the target to be $[0,1]$, not a discrete space.

Comment: Hi @Dave, thanks for your explanation. I have indeed 2 predictors variables which are categorical 0 for Label1 and 1 for Label 2. If I understand, the correct form is: f:RxR -> [0,1]. How do you call this space [0,1] ?

Comment: The interval $[0,1]$ could be called the (closed) unit interval, but $[0,1]$ is fine terminology, too. // I do not follow what you mean about your two predictor variables, particularly after you said you have $15$ predictors.

Comment: True I mixed up with the predictors. I have actually 15 inputs (predictors): {x1,...,x15} -> Model -> y [0,1]. In my mind the model we are looking is a function from RxR to [0,1]. Is that correct?

Comment: How do you wind up with $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ from $15$ input features?

Comment: I winded up to RxR because input dimensions are: `55.5; 1; 0; 1.2;-1;...;2.5`. I don't know if that's correct to say RxR, it should be better R than RxR ?

Comment: I do not follow what that notation means. Could you please explain what it means and how it leads you to $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R?$

Comment: For me RxR designed the set of pairs of real numbers. As I have in inputs a mix for real numbers, I told myself I am in this dimension space. But I am not sure that's why the reason of my question to say if it is correct to say my model is a function from RxR or R^2 to [0,1]

Comment: Why $2$ instead of $15?$

Comment: I could not answer, for me R^2 or RxR represents a couple (x,y)

Comment: Regardless of the notation, why are you using two dimensions instead of fifteen? Shouldn’t you be considering $(x_1,\dots,x_{15})\in\mathbb R^{15}?$

Comment: That's a good suggestion, so the model problem formulation should be: f: R^15 -> [0,1]

Comment: I would at least argue to a $15$-dimensional space, yes, even if it’s not $\mathbb R^{15}$. I am curious, however, how $\mathbb R^2$ even entered the picture.

Comment: I read an article of problem formulation on iris sepal, the dimension sepal was (1.3, 2.4). They put RxR maybe because they have only 2 dimensions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135349/discussion-between-dave-and-user979974).